# XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController: Exit fullscreen when rotate to UIDeviceOrientationPortrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, youtube

I use [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) library for my iOS project. I present video from nonFullScreen mode with code:

```
self.videoPlayer = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:self.youtubeID];
[self.videoPlayer presentInView:self.videoView];
[self.videoPlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

When iPhone rotate to landscape mode i set FullScreen video with catching rotate current ViewController:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    [self.videoPlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];

}
```

But how i can catch rotation XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController in fullScreen video mode?? 
Thank

---

My decision

in this class i add in viewDidLoad observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

And execution

```
- (void)handleDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:(NSNotification *)notification; {

    if ([self.videoPlayer.moviePlayer isFullscreen] && [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

        [self.videoPlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get this information is to subclass `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController` and override `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` and/or `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`

Comment: Thank you! I thought about that too, but chose another option. added my decision in question